# Bootstrap 3 scrollspy - detect scroll on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I want to use the scrollspy to do something it's not necessarily designed for, yet it may do the job.

I have a div `#myTarget` and I simply want to detect when it scrolled to the top of the `.container` and do something each time it does so.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myTarget">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 some-content">.some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="myTarget">#myTarget</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#myTarget'
});

$('#myTarget').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
    console.log('got to the target!');
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mareksmakosz/10uxr7z5/)

P.S. I know I can use other plugins such e.g. [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) but I would like to stick just to Bootstrap if possible.

Comment: ...how would the target scroll at the top of the container? is the container an overflown element? I would suggest creating a function that detects the target's top offset and binding the scroll function to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per bootstrap 3 documentation:

> When scrollspying on elements other than the `<body>`, be sure to have a
>   height set and overflow-y: scroll; applied.

Once you are sure that your scrollspy is working, use this jquery code to detect if you are on top:

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
   var activeSection = $(this).find("li.active a").attr("href");

   if(activeSection === "#section1")
   {
       alert("I have reached to the top.");
   }
});
```

You bind with the event `activate.bs.scrollspy` and whenever it executes you go and fetch the `href` of the current selected item. Then you check if that `href` item is the first item defined in your html. If yes, then you are on top.

**[Check my working JSFIDDLE example.](http://jsfiddle.net/dmr3sgpL/)**

Whenever you scroll down and again come back up, the alert box will show up letting you know that you have reached to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the jQuery scroll event as shown below

```
var current_position = '';

$('#spy-element').on('scroll', function () {
   var activeSection = $("#spy-side").find("li.active a").text();

    if( current_position != activeSection ){
        //do something here

        current_position = activeSection;
    }

});
```

Where #spy-side is the id of the navigation element

Below is my html code for reference:

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="spy-side">

        <div class="well" style="padding:0;">

            <button class="btn btn-block btn-default"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Existing Templates</button>

            <div id="navbar-example2" class="navbar " role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" onclick="return false;">Navigation</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse1 navbar-collapse" id="spy-target">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#template-definition">Template Definition</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#performance-dimensions">Performance Dimensions</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#sub-performance-dimensions">Sub-performance Dimensions</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#weight-allocation">Weight Allocation</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>

    </div>

<div class="col-md-9" >

        <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-12" >

        <div style="position:relative; clear:both;">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn blue btn-sm"><i class="icon-save"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
                <button class="btn  btn-sm"><i class="icon-file"></i>&nbsp;Preview</button>
                <button class="btn  btn-sm"><i class="icon-trash"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <strong id="current-position" style="text-transform:uppercase;"></strong>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="spy-parent" style="position:relative;">
         <div  id="spy-element" class="scrollspy-example">
            <h4 id="template-definition">STEP 1: Template Definition</h4>
```